# Helm Template - Multiple Ingress in a single chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, helm3

I'm writing some helm charts which I want to use as generic charts for deploying various things. When it comes to ingress, I'm toying with ideas as to how to handle multiple ingress entries in values.yaml.. for example;

```
svc:
  app1:
    ingress-internal:
      enabled: true
      annotations:
          kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "internal"
          kubernetes.io/internal-dns.create: "true"
        hosts:
          - host: app1.int.example.com
            paths:
              - /
    ingress-public:
      enabled: true
      annotations:
          kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "external"
          kubernetes.io/internal-dns.create: "true"
        hosts:
          - host: app1.example.com
            paths:
              - /
```

I plan to have one values file which contains a bunch of semi-static config which is managed by one team, and is of no visibility to the app config teams. So the values file could contain multiple app entries (although the chart will hand one at a time).. I do this with this logic:

```
{{- if (index .Values.svc (include "app.refName" .) "something") -}}
```

Where `app.refName` is in this case equal to `app1`.

I'm toying with the idea now about multiple ingresses... I'm thinking along the lines of;

```
{{- $ingressName := regexMatch "/^ingress-*/" index ( .Values.svc (include "app.refName" .)) -}}
{{- $ingress := index .Values.svc (include "bvnk.refame" .) $ingressName -}}
{{- if $ingress -}}
```

Am I right in saying `regexMatch` would match both `ingress-internal` and `ingress-public`? And then I could use `$ingressName` as the name of the ingress entry... but then how would I do the following:

- Ensure it loops through all `^ingress-*` entries and creates a manifest for each?
- Do nothing if none exist? (I suppose I could use a default to return an emtpy dict maybe?)

Is there a better way of aceiving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an array of ingress definitions. For example:

```yaml
svc:
  app1:
    ingress:
      - name: internal
        annotations:
          kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "internal"
          kubernetes.io/internal-dns.create: "true"
        hosts:
          - host: app1.int.example.com
            paths:
              - /
      - name: public
        annotations:
          kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "external"
          kubernetes.io/internal-dns.create: "true"
        hosts:
          - host: app1.example.com
            paths:
              - /
```

Then, in your template file, range over the ingresses:

```yaml
{{- range .Values.svc.app1.ingress }}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
...
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a much more simple approach which works well :)